# Cannot Deploy Workflow With Time-Dependent Workflow Actions

Tags: workflow, deployment, change-set, time-dependent-workflow

I am trying to update a `Workflow Rule` which has `Time-Dependent Workflow Actions` through change set, but I am blocked by the below error.

> This workflow rule currently has pending actions in the workflow queue. To delete, please remove those pending actions.

However, when I look in the queue to try to "remove those pending actions" there are none.

[image: Empty Time-Based Workflow Queue]

**What steps can I take to fix this situation?**

Comment: what I remember from my past experience is that you need to specify exact name of workflow in above search.

Comment: I have tried that and many other search strategies, they all turn up nothing. The included screenshot was just the simplest to post.

Comment: i am able to see pending items in my org with above criteria. do you verify that you have verified in target org.

Comment: @Himanshu Yes I am certain I have verified in the target org and there are no results.

Comment: I recall I had to deactivate the workflow in the target org and deploy via the changeset a deactivated workflow.  Once deployment was done, I reactivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We decided to manually edit the `Workflow Rule` instead of updating it via `Change Set`.

Comment: We have a deployment process and the manual changes will be overridden if the metadata is not in the repository. But when I check in the metadata and try to deploy the metadata, it is throwing error like "This workflow rule currently has pending actions in the workflow queue.  To delete, please remove those pending actions.". Any ideas?

Comment: Has anyone found the solution for this issue yet?

Comment: I deleted all records have processed by this Workflow Role, and this issue was fixed